# Change the CSS of the first Argument of @Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: css, asp.net, razor

is there a way to change the CSS style of only the First argument "Add To Cart" ? 
example changing font or color of the Text?

```
@Ajax.ActionLink( "Add To Cart", "addToCart", "Product", new { idProduct = @item.idProduct, quantity = 1 }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", }, new { @class = "item-add-btn" } )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps using pseudo-class in css, first-of-type or first-child. see example

```
li:first-of-type {
  background-color: yellow;
}

li:first-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

[CSS3 :first-of-type Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp)